# iOS URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier returns nil on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I'm trying to add iCloud support to my app and have two devices for testing, an iPhone and an iPad. Both are running iOS 8.1 and are connected to the same Apple account. When I check the Settings for iCloud, I can see that other apps are successfully using iCloud on both devices. However, while on the iPhone everything works ok (i.e. I get the "Using local storage: 0" message shortly after starting the app), on the iPad it crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

Turns out `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier : nil]` returns `nil`. What could be the cause of this behaviour considering that I'm running the exact same build on both devices, so there are no differences in any configurations, entitlements, etc.

**EDIT**
Actually, seems iCloud is in general unavailable on the iPad. `[NSFileManager defaultManager].ubiquityIdentityToken` returns `nil` as well, and that should be a fairly reliable way to figure out if the iCloud can be used or not. :(

Comment: Show the code by which you are making this call. It needs to be on a background thread so you can't use its results right away; I suspect that you are not taking account of the asynchronous nature of the call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked `ubiquityIdentityToken` instead and it is `nil`, so it's likely not a matter of async call problems.

Comment: Actually if you are running into issues with [NSFileManager defaultManager].ubiquityIdentityToken and which are solved by signing into and out of iCloud.... then you are running into the bug reported here: 18702493 and 18940230. Supposedly 8.1.1 fixes this :) See my fuller response below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iCloud sync daemons seem somewhat flaky still on iOS 8.1. On devices that are having problems use the settings app to sign out of that iCloud account, and sign in again. Reboot the device for good measure and try again. Repeat if necessary.

This normally clears any iCloud weirdness for me...

Other than that, are your iCloud entitlements configured correctly? Check both Xcode Capabilities and Certificates & Identifiers on the Dev Centre website and see that both think these are ok. If other apps on the affected device are able to sync documents (via Documents & Data OR iCloud Drive) then it's probably your config.

Also, don't rely on Settings telling you other apps are able to sync documents - are those apps ACTUALLY syncing documents (so create documents in the apps and see if they actually sync)... What Settings says does not always reflect what the underlying daemon processes are actually doing.

Comment: You are right, signing out of iCloud and back in added an extra option to the settings - "Documents & Data" - which seems to be a critical point to making all of this work. Will likely include this pointer as a tip in the app in case users are having the exact same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to check for iCloud availability is to check (as you stated):

```
id icToken = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
```

The docs state the following:

> When iCloud is currently available, this property contains an opaque object representing the identity of the current user. If iCloud is unavailable for any reason or there is no logged-in user, the value of this property is nil. Accessing the value of this property is relatively fast so you can check the value at launch time from your app’s main thread.

However, apparently on iOS 8.1 this got broken and when you DO THAT on the main thread iOS terminates you... and CRASH! Little Birdies are saying an iOS update will shortly fix this.

See the following bug reports: 18848310, 18940230

Comment: what value is it when it ISNT nil??? is it a string value or int?  how do i return this token value as a NSString??

Comment: Don't remember, but the the code included above is correct. It returns an id to some kind of object as I recall. Stick that line in you App Delegate and see what comes back in the debugger.